# How to focus on multiple textboxes and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot text boxes in a form that get a class added to them when submitted
then that class gets a `:first` selector along with `.focus()` to focus on the text box that didn't receive any input but it cutoffs the message above the text box.

So how do I move the scroll bar in conjunction with the `.focus()` on text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you're after right?

```
$(function() {

    $('input, textarea').each(function() {
        var os = $(this).offset().top;
        $(this).bind('focus', function() {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: os}, 300);
        });
    });

});
```

When you focus either an input or a textarea it will scroll to it.

Here's a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fExhw/

**EDIT**

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('error')) {
                var firstError = $('.error:first');
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: firstError.offset().top}, 300);
                firstError.focus();   
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fExhw/1/ (hit the submit button at the bottom)

Ok updated it to what I think you're after.

Comment: yeah something like that, except in reverse... because the submit button is on the bottom of the form so it would need to scroll up to the textbox that has the class for ie .haserror:first so if doesnt have the class it doesnt scroll to it and if they all have it or some to scroll to the first one...

Answer (score 0):

In the textbox's `focus` eventhandler, get the textbox's coords and use jQUery `scrollLeft/scrollTop` to scroll the page accordingly.

**Example (starting point, may need refinement):**

```
function scrollToTextbox(id) {
  var coords = $('#' + id).offset();
  $(document).scrollLeft(coords.left);
  $(document).scrollTop(coords.top);
}
```

**Note:** You *may* have to adjust the scroll a bit (either by adding few pixels or by subtracting) based on how markup and styling is used in your page.

Comment: can you possibly elaborate a bit more on how to get the coords of the textbox and then implement scrollTop?

Comment: Added an example. This should get you started.

Comment: what if i have multiple textboxes? because i add the class .haserror for the focus to each textbox that isnt filled so if its filled i obviously dont want it to scroll & focus to the one above it? if that makes some sense...

Comment: Not sure if I understand your point. Are you saying you want to scroll to input that has the class `hasError`?

Comment: yes, so if the user did not fill in a textbox, it adds the class hasError so their could be multiple textboxes with that class and i want to scroll to the one with that class similar to .hasError:first.focus... hope that made more sense

Comment: Well, so when you add that class, you can send the `id` of the textbox to this function and it'll scroll it accordingly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: im not sure the 1st answer by tfbox is more less what i was thinking just with some adjustments with use of my class and scrolling up rather than down...

Answer (score 0):

Have you used [jQuery.scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)? I've had great luck with it solving similar tasks.